# dynamic dropdown menu not working

Tags: php, jquery, session

i'm trying to make a notification tab work but do not seem to get it right. The dropdown is working fine but the ajax call  is not working right, when viewed with firebug there are results but not seen in the dropdown.Quite confusing. (note the dropdown menu is located in header and can only be displayed if the session is initialised) here is the ajax used in jquery:

```
function load_notifications(view=''){
   $.ajax({
       url: "notification/new_friends.php",
       method: "POST",
       data:{view:"view"},
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data){

           $(".dropdown-menu").html(data.notification);
if(data.unseen_notification>0){
    $(".badge1").html(data.unseen_notification);
}
    }

   });
        //$(".dynamic-notification").load("notification/pm_n.php");
   // $(".dynamic-notification-f").load("notification/new_friends.php");
};
load_notifications();
$(document).on("click",".count_friend", function(){
    load_notifications('yes');
});
//loads every 2 seconds for chat
setInterval(function(){load_notifications();},2000);
```

here is the new_friends.php content:

```
<?php
include '../includes/dbconfig.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['view'])) {

if($_POST['view'] !=''){
$update="update friends set count='1' where friend_one=:session and count='0'";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($update);
$stmt->bindValue(":session", $_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();
}
$sql123="select id from friends where friend_two=:sess_uname and count='0'";
$stmt123=$conn->prepare($sql123);
$stmt123->bindValue(":sess_uname", $_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt123->execute();
$request_count=$stmt123->fetchColumn();
//$count_friend=$stmt123->rowCount();
/*$sql_f_count="select *from user where user_id=:session_id and activated='1' limit 1";
$stmt_f_count=$conn->prepare($sql_f_count);
$stmt_f_count->bindValue(":session_id", $_SESSION['id']);
$stmt_f_count->execute();
$user_details=$stmt_f_count->fetchAll();
$friend_badge=$user_details[0]['friend_count_badge'];*/
require "notification/friend_request_notification.php";
// $new_friends="<span class='dropdown'><a href='#' data-placement='bottom' class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' title='Friend Requests' data-html='true'><span class='count_friend' style=' height:33px; width:30px;'><span class='badge1 label label-pill'>".$count."</span><img src='img/logo/group-button-white.png' style='height:25px; width:27px;' alt='new_friends_alert'></span></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span>"; 
//if($request_count[0]>0){
//$new_friends="<a href='#' data-placement='bottom' class='btn' data-trigger='focus' title='Friend Requests' data-toggle='popover' data-html='true' data-content='".$friend_requests."'><span class='count_friend' style=' height:33px; width:30px;'><img src='img/logo/group-button-white.png' style='height:25px; width:27px;' alt='new_friends_alert'></span><span class='badge'>".$friend_badge."</span></a>";
/*}else{
$new_friends="<a href='all_notifications.php'><img src='img/logo/group-button-black.png' style='height:25px; width:27px;' alt='new_friends_alert'></a>";
}*/
//echo $new_friends;
//}
$data=array(
'notification'=>$friend_requests,
'unseen_notification' =>$request_count[0][0]
);
```

and the code for friend requests output:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
require_once 'includes/dbconfig.inc.php';
$sql = "select * from friends where friend_two=:session and accepted='0' order by friends_date_made asc";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(":session", $_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();
$numrows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$friend_requests="";
if ($numrows < 1) {
$friend_requests = "You do not have any friend requests";
echo "$friend_requests";
exit();
} else {
foreach ($numrows as $i=>$row1 ) {
$reqid = $row1['friend_id'];
$user1 = $row1['friend_one'];
$datemade = $row1['friends_date_made'];
$datemade1 = strftime("%B %d, %y", strtotime($datemade));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname=:user1 LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(":user1", $user1);
$stmt->execute();
$thumbrow = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user1avatar = $thumbrow[$i]['avatar'];
$user1id=$thumbrow[$i]['user_id'];

if ($user1avatar =="") {
$user1pic = '<img src="img/avatardefault.png" height="50" style="float:left;" width="50" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';
} else {
$user1pic = '<img src="../user/user/'.$user1id.'/'.$user1avatar.'" height="50" style="float:left;" width="50" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';

}
$friend_requests .= '<li><div id="'.$reqid.'" float="right" class="friendrequests">
<a href="home.php?u='.$user1.'">'. $user1pic .'</a>
<div class="user_info '.$reqid.'" id="'.$reqid.'"><small>' . $datemade1 . '</small>
<a href="home.php?u='.$user1.'">'.$user1.'</a> is requesting your friendship<br /><br />
<button id="'.$reqid.'" name="'.$_SESSION['uname'].'" sess="'.$_SESSION['id'].'" class="accept_btn btn btn-warning">Accept</button><span class="show-spinner"></span> or
<button id="'.$reqid.'" name="'.$_SESSION['uname'].'" sess="'.$_SESSION['id'].'" class="reject_btn btn btn-warning">Reject</button>
</div>
</div><hr></li>';


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is drop down populate, if can you help:

```
<?php
// Assume $db is a PDO object

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=populatedropdown', "root", "");

$query = $dbh->query("select * from position"); // Run your query

echo '<form action="populate.php" method="get">';
echo '<select name="populate">'; // Open your drop down box



// Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box


echo '<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">';

echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: i think that my intention is different ,my php code is ok i think its the jquery that is creating the problem. As firebug outputs the desired json code but my notification and unseen_notification values from json is not getting populated in the dropdown-menu class.